# How to get a list of all available targets in Yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to configure a custom Yocto build for a embedded system.

I need to add packages to both the target fs and the tool chain.

Currently I'm only trying to add packages that already has a recipe.

For example by adding `IMAGE_INSTALL += " boost-dev"` and `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "boost-dev"` I can add boost to both targetfs and tool chain.

**What I want to do**

The rootfs built by the Yocto is very complete and has a lot of libraries, but the tool chain only has the most basic ones.

I want to add the missing libraries to the tool chain.

**Question:**

How do I find the names of available libraries?

Like `boost-dev`, I did a lot of googling to find out by adding the name `boost-dev` to `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK` I can get what I want.

But things like OpenGL and OpenCL, even though I know they are provided by `/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-graphics/imx-gpu-viv` in my case, how shall I find out what package name shall I add to `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more googling and found the way to get package names used by a bitbake target by looking at dependencies.

By doing [`bitbake -g <packagename> -u depexp`](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Inspect_DEPENDS), the dependency among packages are shown, so are the name of all packages involved in the Yocto build.

For example, `devil` package depends on `devil-dev`, hence doing `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "devil-dev"` in `meta-toolchain%.bbappend` adds devil to the tool chain.

The package names found this way may not be complete, specifically some child-packages included in a parent-package may not be shown here.

When this happens, first locate the parent-package that is likely to contain the child-package, then find the `.bb` file and `.inc` file for it.

In those files there's likely a `PACKAGES` variable that tells what child-package are provided by this package. Those child-package can then be added to `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK`.